# Firebase validate ID Token - Node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

In the front end I can initialize Firebase and create an ID token.

In the back-end I have added the following code to app.js

```
var admin = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccount = require('./mywebproject-206275-firebase-adminsdk-eikjj-5a21010452.json');

admin.initializeApp({
 credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
 databaseURL: "https://mywebproject-206275.firebaseio.com"
});
```

If I comment out admin.initializeApp it will run. If I try to run with admin.initializeApp... it will return 502 bad gateway.

All I want to do is validate a token sent to the server. I have checked the node_modules folder and firebase-admin is installed. I generated the JSON file directly from the Firebase Console. The JSON file is in  the same folder as the app.js file.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: From the provided code everything seems fine. Can you tell us more about the error? Where do you get it? Is there a message or just the code?

Comment: Thanks - the message is on browser.  ie no pages from the site open while using admin.initializeApp.   Response in browser:

502 Bad Gateway
nginx/1.10.3

Comment: Ok, can you get node logs somehow? Probably, it throws some error on initialisation and the error message will help a lot with figuring out the root of the problem.

Comment: Response:   throw new error_1.FirebaseAppError(error_1.AppErrorCodes.DUPLICATE_AP
P, 'The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp() ' 
+
                ^
Error: The default Firebase app already exists. This means you called initializeApp()
 more than once without providing an app name as the second argument. In most cases y
ou only need to call initializeApp() once. But if you do want to initialize multiple 
apps, pass a second argument to initializeApp() to give each app a unique name.

Comment: Many thanks  -that has identified the error.  Add called previously in older route and forgot to remove.  Thanks again.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"